# Python 3.2 skip a line in csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

How do I skip a line of records in a CSV when using a DictReader?

Code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('test2.csv'))
# Skip first line
reader.next()
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learn.py", line 3, in <module>
    reader.next()
AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: nothing to do with this problem, but you should be opening your file like this: `open('test2.csv', newline='')` ... see the csv.reader docs

Comment: I read the CSV.Reader doc.  This attribute appears to help preserve multiline CSVs.  Since my CSV file is multiline, would it still be prudent to add `newline=''` to my open command?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You use `next(reader)` instead.

Source: [csv.DictReader documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.__next__)

Comment: This is because it's Python 3, not Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

Since Python 2.6 you should use next(foo) instead of foo.next().

Answer (score 6):

It was considered a mistake in python2 to have the method called `next()` instead of `__next__()`

`next(obj)` now calls `obj.__next__()` just like `str`, `len` etc. as it should.

You usually wouldn't call `obj.__next__()` directly just as you wouldn't call `obj.__str__()` directly if you wanted the string representation of an object.

Handy to know if you find yourself writing unusual iterators

Comment: Thanks for the context!