# How to skip pre header lines with csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, csv

I want to `csv.DictReader` to deduce the field names from the file. [The docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) say *"If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames."*, but in my case the first row containts a title and the 2nd row which contains the names.

I can't apply `next(reader)` as per [Python 3.2 skip a line in csv.DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787723/python-3-2-skip-a-line-in-csv-dictreader) because the fieldname assignment takes place when initializing the reader (or I'm doing it wrong).

The csvfile (exported from Excel 2010, [original source](http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/doc/CanVec_EntitiesCodesFileNames_EntitesCodesNomsDeFichier_v1_1_1.xls)):

```
CanVec v1.1.0,,,,,,,,,^M
Entity,Attributes combination,"Specification Code
Point","Specification Code
Line","Specification Code
Area",Generic Code,Theme,"GML - Entity name
Shape - File name
Point","GML - Entity name
Shape - File name
Line","GML - Entity name
Shape - File name
Area"^M
Amusement park,Amusement park,,,2260012,2260009,LX,,,LX_2260009_2^M
Auto wrecker,Auto wrecker,,,2360012,2360009,IC,,,IC_2360009_2^M
```

My code:

```
f = open(entities_table,'rb')
try:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
    f.seek(0)

    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=dialect)
    print 'I think the field names are:\n%s\n' % (reader.fieldnames)

    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i < 20:
            print row
            i = i + 1

finally:
    f.close()
```

Current results:

```
I think the field names are:
['CanVec v1.1.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Desired result:

```
I think the field names are:
['Entity','Attributes combination','"Specification Code Point"',...snip]
```

I realize it would be expedient to simply delete the first row and carry on, but I'm trying to get as close to just reading the data in situ as I can and minimize manual intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used islice from itertools. My header was in the last line of a big preamble. I have passed preamble and used hederline for fieldnames:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    '''Pass preamble'''
    n = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        n += 1
        if 'same_field_name' in line: # line with field names was found
            h = line.split(',')
            break
    f.close()
    f = islice(open(i, "r"), n, None)

    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames = h)
```

Comment: This is a more flexible solution, provided one knows with certainty one field name (a reasonable expectation). Thanks.

Comment: I expect, @PavelTrufanov, that closing ``f`` inside the context manager should not cause any direct problems, but I'm not sure what happens when you re-open the file, which gets a new reference, and then assign that reference to ``f`` again. I'm not sure if the new reference to a file handle is closed in these circumstances by the context manager.

Comment: But anyway, @PavelTrufanov, your close and re-open seem entirely superfluous. Since you've already read through the file to the point you need to, there's no need to close, re-open, and then effectively seek through to the same point in the file! Just drop those two lines and don't import ``islice`` and I think the result is the same!

Comment: However, what this approach could achieve, @PavelTrufanov - although I emphasise again re-opening a file inside the context manager is not something I am confident with - is you could could ``islice`` to ``n - 1`` lines. This enables ``DictReader`` to process the headers for you, after you've found out where they are, and you no longer have to rely on a simple split on comma, which may be likely to break, depending on what your input data looks like.

Answer (score 19):

After `f.seek(0)`, insert:

```
next(f)
```

to advance the file pointer to the second line before initializing the `DictReader`.

Comment: doh! of course. Many thanks for your patience with a beginner.

Comment: Someone said: "I realize it would be expedient to simply delete the first row and carry on, but I'm trying to get as close to just reading the data in situ as I can and minimize manual intervention."

Answer (score 0):

#### General solution

This is a more general solution for when it's **not certain at which row the headers will arrive**.

This solution also **cleans up the headers** - expecting the first "word" (space separated) as the actual column header and trailing characters to be treated as comments (and dropped).

#### Not possible wholly within csv.DictReader

It's not possible to handle skip lines inside [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Firstly it doesn't have a "number of skip lines" feature (like Pandas) but also, we don't know how many lines it's going to be. So it's determined that external processing is required. The file contents need to be read and processed.

#### Clean solution

Suggestions for improvement are welcome, but this solution avoids importing unnecessary libraries and does not use broken hacks like [closing a file within a context manager and re-opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26074856) (!).

#### Python 3

```py
import csv

FILENAME = "data.csv"


with open(FILENAME, newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        if "known_field_name" in line:
            break
    else:
        sys.exit("Error: Headers not found")
    fieldnames = [(field.strip().split() or [""])[0] for field in line.split(",")]
    rows = [row for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)]

print("Field names are: {}".format(fieldnames)) 

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Note this code will not produce the results expected in the question because the column headers include spaces in the test data, and this solution has a specific feature to clean column headers up.

Just drop that feature if spaces are allowed in column headers.

#### Slurping whole file

This solution slurps the whole file in order to discard the file handle early, as it's intended for a smaller data set. If a large data set is in play then keep processing within the `csvfile` context manager and don't slurp the whole file into an initial list.

#### Field names processing

The `(field.strip().split() or [""])[0]` step is used to get a clean column header. Because `field.strip()` can produce an empty string, then `field.strip().split()` can also produce an empty list, and `[][0]` would then raise an exception.

This is where `... or [""]` ensures there is a list of length of 1 or greater to avoid raising the `IndexError`.

Indexing the first item is necessary to separate the first word from other commentary in the column header cell (no newlines or commas allowed, see below).

#### Vulnerabilities

The field names processing has necessarily been done manually, outside of `csv`. In particular, the simple approach of split on comma is expected to provide all column headers from a single line.

- Do not allow commas inside column headers
- Do not allow line breaks inside column headers

If either or both of these two rules are broken this code will not "realise" and processing will break.