# Equivalent of readline() for python's csv.DictReader

Tags: python

Is there no equivalent for `readline()` while using `csv.DictReader`? I need to skip the header row of the file before looping and using `readline()` is a good way to do so using the normal reader variable.

Comment: There is prior art to this ;-) Like the answers suggest, One could also look at [Python 3.2 skip a line in csv.DictReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787723/python-3-2-skip-a-line-in-csv-dictreader) to just name the first I came across ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DictReader` object is an iterator, so calling its `next` method (by calling `next` on it) should skip (or return) a row just as `readline` would.

> I need to skip the header row of the file before looping

`DictReader` objects do not specify a header row. All subsequent rows (after the first) are inserted as values in a dict, with the first row as keys, like so:

```
r,t,s
1,2,3
2,4,6
```

---

```
>>> f = open('sample.csv')
>>> r = csv.DictReader(f)
>>> next(r)
{'s': '3', 't': '2', 'r': '1'}
>>> next(r)
{'s': '6', 't': '4', 'r': '2'}
```

So to skip the first row, you have to call `next` on the file object itself and then pass that file object to create your `DictReader`

Answer (score 1):

`DictReader()` is an [*iterator* object](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator). Use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on the object to get individual rows:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(fileobj)
row = next(reader, None)
```

The second argument to `next()` is a default value to return if the iterable is empty; so `row` is set to `None` if there are no more rows to read.

Incidentally, this works on file objects too. And because `DictReader()` *automatically* will read the first row if you did not specify any fieldnames, if you want to prevent the very first line from being used you'll have to move the `fileobj` to the next line before reading from the `DictReader()` object:

```
next(fileobj, None)  # skip first line of the file
reader = csv.DictReader(fileobj)
```